# Asymptotic property for summation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

We have $\sum_{i = 0}^{n}a_{i}$ diverges and we also know that $a_{n} \sim b_{n}$. We also restrict both $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ are two positive sequence. Then we want to show that $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \frac{a_{i}}{b_{i}} \sim n$. From $a_{n} \sim b_{n}$, we know that $\sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_{i} \sim \sum_{i = 0}^{n} b_{i}$. Then i'm not sure how to go from here to what I want. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is your definition of $\sim$?

Comment: @user58697  if $a_{n} \sim b_{n}$ ,then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} = 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c_n = \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$. By definition, $\lim_{n\to\infty} c_n = 1$. Now you can forget $a_n$ and $b_n$, and concentrate on $c_n$. That is, prove that $\lim\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}c_i}{n} = 1$.

Now observe that $c_n = 1 + d_n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty} d_n = 0$. It means that you just need to prove that $\lim\dfrac{\sum_{i=0}^{n}d_i}{n} = 0$. This is a very straight-forward $\epsilon, N$ reasoning. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Hmm, how do you actually prove $\sum d_i=o(n)$ ? This is not that straightforward. $d_i$ can be $\frac 1{n^\epsilon}$ and $\sum d_i=O(n^{1-\epsilon})$ just barely enough to be an $o(n)$...

Comment: @zwim Take small $\epsilon$. Find $N$ such that $|d_{N+i} \lt \epsilon$ for all $i$. Let the sum until $N$ be $S_N$. Take $M$ such that $\frac{S_N}{M} \lt \epsilon$. Observe that $\frac{S_M }{M} \lt \epsilon$.